# not able to iterate through multiple pages while scraping data

Tags: selenium, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, iteration

So, I have to scrape the review and ratings for the product on flipkart.
I need to scrape at least 30-40 review and rating. So for that I have to click on the next page as on 1st page only 10 reviews are present. Below is the code that I am using to check if my code is able to click on the next page.

'''

```
driver =webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")
```

'''

```
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/hp-15s-ryzen-3-dual-core-3250u-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-256-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-15s-gr0012au-laptop/product-reviews/itm9e1f8deeed35f?pid=COMFZHFWBE7APPH2&lid=LSTCOMFZHFWBE7APPH2AR705G&marketplace=FLIPKART&page=2)
```

'''

```
for page in range(4):
   
   try:
       next_butt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//nav[@class='yFHi8N']/a/span")

       if next_butt.text == 'NEXT':
           next_butt.click()
   except NoSuchElementException:
       continue
time.sleep(1)
```

When ever I run this code what I observe that it is able to click on next button but after 1st iteration it clicks on pervious button, so I am not getting ahead.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this URL which you have shared :

```
https://www.flipkart.com/hp-15s-ryzen-3-dual-core-3250u-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-256-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-15s-gr0012au-laptop/product-reviews/itm9e1f8deeed35f?pid=COMFZHFWBE7APPH2&lid=LSTCOMFZHFWBE7APPH2AR705G&marketplace=FLIPKART&page=2
```

in the end you would see `page = 2`, so if I change that to `page = 3` I would see 3rd page reviews without having **Selenium bot** to click on `Next button.`

So what I would do here is to parse the `page_number int` variable like below :

**sample code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
page_number = 1
for page in range(4):
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/hp-15s-ryzen-3-dual-core-3250u-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-256-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-15s-gr0012au-laptop/product-reviews/itm9e1f8deeed35f?pid=COMFZHFWBE7APPH2&lid=LSTCOMFZHFWBE7APPH2AR705G&marketplace=FLIPKART&page=%s" % page_number)
    #scrape anything you want here
    page_number = page_number + 1
    sleep(5)
```